# Worklight 5.06 - How can I retrieve a large amount of data from JSONStore?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, jsonstore

I am developing an app in Worklight 5.06. My app needs to store around 15,000 documents for the same collection into JSONStore. I found that when I try to retrieve all of them at one time, it took me around 2 minutes to complete this action. Is there any ways to boost the performance?

Please feel free to give any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: What method are you using to retrieve the documents?

Comment: Are they big? How do you store them in the first place? Why would you retrieve 15,000 documents at a time (not for display purposes I assume)?

Comment: Please post your code showing how you are getting the data and storing it, so that we can see if there are any improvements we can make.

Comment: Also include what search fields you are indexing, and an idea of how big each document is, as these two affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest you do the following:

- [Upgrade to the latest version of Worklight](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/signup.do?source=swg-worklight&S_PKG=ov1268&S_CMP=web_dw_rt_swd), performance tweaks have been part of new releases.
- Read the [JSONStore Performance](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_performance.html) section in the documentation. I linked to the documentation from v6.2, but most, if not all, of the statements translate into previous Worklight versions with JSONStore support.
- Read my blog post on [Offline Patterns](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/offline_patterns?lang=en) and re-think your offline experience strategy. It may not apply to every application, but when possible you should selectively allow users to pick what content they want available offline. I used two popular applications in the App Store as examples. [Spotify](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/resource/BLOGS_UPLOADED_IMAGES/spotify.gif) allows users to pick certain songs for offline availability, instead of loading all songs for the offline experience. [Google Maps](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/resource/BLOGS_UPLOADED_IMAGES/gmaps.gif) allows users to pick certain map regions to be available while lacking network connectivity, instead of loading all map data for offline use.
- **Update Sept. 7 2014:** Read the blog post on JSONStore performance [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/jsonstore_performance_breakdown?lang=en).